# Why were the Skrulls already in orbit around C-53?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

As the Skrulls rifled through Vers' memories, it looks like that's how they learned Lawson was on C-53. But then when Vers busts free; she falls to C-53 ... so why were they already in orbit around it?

Did I miss something about what the Skrulls knew about her origins?

Comment: One assumes that having identified that she's from Earth (which they would have done within the first few minutes of mind-reading), they traveled here *while conducting the rest of the interrogation*.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, but they were looking for Lawson, right? Did they just head here because that was **a** lead?

Comment: Surely they already knew the other Skrulls were with Lawson on C-53. The leader (I don't remember his name) had (this might be spoilers, so we'll just say) friends who were in her custody. My guess is they were trying to find out what happened to her on C-53.

Comment: @Chipster I thought they were looking for Lawson, and used Vers' memories to locate her. So I don't understand why they were already there.

Comment: The last place they knew, Lawson was on C-53, correct?

Comment: @Chip I'm asking the questions here!

Comment: lol. I was just trying to point out that theoretically they should know C-53 is where Lawson was. Considering what they were trying find, it's not that out of the ordinary to be headed to C-53.

Comment: They knew Lawson/Mar-Vell had been on earth, and died there. The location they were looking for was the location of her laboratory, which was actually orbiting earth, and cloaked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Massive spoilers ahoy!

> As I understood it, they already knew that Lawson was on Earth -- in fact, they were even there themselves years ago, when they retrieved the black box that contained the last recording of Carol's voice before she crashed.

But...

> ...a planet is a big place. The thing they *didn't* have, and which they were trying to find in her memory, were the coordinates of *where* on Earth she and Lawson were headed at the time of the crash. (Although as it turned out, they weren't coordinates on the surface at all; they were describing a point in orbit.)

Comment: Isn't your first spoiler tag incorrect? They only gain that information later on, they're not always in possession of it.

Comment: Yeah I think the implication is that Talos obtained the black box recording while impersonating Director Keller. But Talos's family, and the other Skrull refugees, had at least been on Mar-Vell's orbiting lab, if not earth (although maybe earth), since 1989 or earlier.

Comment: @Paul Are you sure? Didn't Maria say the black box had been destroyed? Or was the implication SHIELD had retrieved it before USAF got to it?

Comment: @AzorAhai: Maria said she was *told* the black box was destroyed. The implication was that the crash was covered up, by SHIELD and/or the Air Force, presumably due to the extra-terrestrial power source in use.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But doesn't the Skrull she's talking to imply that Skrull shapeshifting powers are the reason it was believed to be destroyed? (Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact quotes from that scene.)

Comment: @AdmiralJota: I think you're referring to Talos saying that he has a knack for getting into places where he isn't supposed to be. He says that in the run-up to revealing that he has the black box recording. He also seems unfamiliar with the medium it's recorded on (CD). To me, that read as if he'd obtained it while disguised as Director Keller during the events of the movie; not that he'd been hanging onto it for six years. Both are possible though. (He also seems aware that Vers is actually Carol Danvers and worked with Mar-Vell, so he must have been around in 1989.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, yeah, I got that. I meant; didn't it seem like the black box had been missing for six years? I guess I figured it was taken by the Skrulls right away but I suppose it could have been taken by Talos as Keller. (Which would explain how they got it onto a CD in the first place).

Comment: @AzorAhai: “didn't it seem like the black box had been missing for six years”. Not to me. It seemed like it was kept secret, like a bunch of other stuff about the crash. (The files about it had a lot of stuff redacted, for example.)

Comment: Fury's comment during the film imply SHIELD didn't know anything about the crash; he's as much in the dark as Carol is, and the sign indicates that Pegasus, at the rime, was a joint NASA/USAF project. He assumes the coverup wasn't because of the power source, but because it was a billion+ dollar program that failed when Lawson stole the prototype and crashed it and Pegasus was embarrassed and so covered the entire thing up, including the black box. If SHIELD had had it, they'd have known about alien involvement already, whereas Fury seemed taken aback initially.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Nick Fury was a much lower ranking member of shield in the movie, much earlier in his career and not yet the director with knowledge about everything in his head. The Project Pegasus base was a Shield facility, but he was learning about the redacted files with Carol because he wasn't at that level yet. I believe he showed his ID in the start stating level 3 or level C, when there are much higher levels of knowledge (1-10 plus Alpha according to an MCU wiki).

Comment: @IronSean, one should also bear in mind the revelation that SHIELD (and the US government) was infiltrated by HYDRA. As *Agents of SHIELD* revealed, HYDRA had previously used NASA as a cover for their own operations, outside of direct SHIELD involvement. It's entirely possible that if anyone at SHIELD knew about it, it was only the moles.